# Bug with Longitude in JSON & KMLGoogle "Takeout" Location data

Tags: json, google-api, location, privacy, google-location-services

Location History data (downloaded from [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout)) is reporting incorrect Longitude on both the JSON and KML exports.  **Latitude is correct but  Longitude is showing in the 304 to 305 range** (after dividing by 10<sup>7</sup>), instead of the negative number it should be in my case. It seems like the longitude data is simply "too high", by 430 (×10<sup>7</sup>).

The problem shows in a JSON Location History I retrieved a few days ago; today I tried re-generating the downloads in **both `JSON` and `KML`** and both are still affected by this issue.

The same problem is reported by someone else [here](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/4595364) about 4 days ago but that's the only other mention of this issue I can find online.

Thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: ...nothin' huh?  :‎

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/319067/110651): (no thanks to Google on this one!)

> They seem to have an integer overflow error in preparing the data for
>   the takeout (downloading the kml directly from google maps for a
>   specific day works correct).
>
> **If the number is greater than 1800000000** (for latitude, also comparing
>   to 900000000 would work) you need to **subtract 2^32 (=4294967296)** and
>   you get the correct latitudeE7 or longitudeE7.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
>   latitudeE7 = 4233738877 - 4294967296 = -61228419 (= 6.12 South)
>   longitudeE7 = 1066510714 (= 106.7 East, no conversion here)
> ```